# Большая задержка при печати с удаленного компьютера на общий принтер

Tags: hp, linux, принтер, ubuntu

Доброго времени суток.

В отделе стоит 1 принтер на 7 компьютеров: 4 стационарных(ubuntu 10.04) и 3 ноутбука(win). Все компьютеры подключены к корпоративной сети через 24-портовый коммутатор, который подключен через еще один коммутатор к серверу.
Принтер *HP LaserJet 3050* подключен к стационарному компьютеру. На принтере включен общий доступ.

Все компьютеры, кроме 1 печатают практически без задержек, а на 1 стационарном задержки бывают от 10 минут до нескольких часов(приходят на почту отсканированные счета размером около 30 Мб). Текстовые файлы печатаются нормально. С других машин сканы печатаются тоже нормально.

Установлена была Ubuntu 9.04, поставил 10.04 - не помогло.

Где копать дальше еще? Или возможно, что-то посоветуете?

Comment: Прошу прощения, что еще не отписался по данному вопросу. Времени не было попасть на этот офис, да и не нужно было особо. Может быть на этой неделе попаду и оглашу результаты... В любом случае, спасибо всем, кто проявил внимание к моему вопросу. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Все компьютеры подключены к корпоративной сети через 24-портовый коммутатор, который подключен через еще один коммутатор к серверу.

Зачем?

> Где копать дальше еще? Или возможно, что-то посоветуете?

Попробуйте подключить на другой порт свитча, если ситуация сохраниться, следующий шаг - замена сетевой карты. Проверить хождение через свитч пакетов разных размеров можно так

> ping IP-address -s размер-пакета

Comment: Зачем? Я тоже это спрашивал, но никто внятно не мог объяснить с какой целью так делалось, тем более, что в обход второго свитча к серверу меньшее расстояние... Объяснение было одно: "оно так было раньше...""Проверить хождение через свитч пакетов"Я тоже хотел это проверить, но их админ сказал, что с сетью все нормально. Также хотел попробовать подключить другой компьютер к данному порту свитча.

Comment: Находил решение похожей проблемы на сайте Майкрософта: связано с настройкой задержки приема пакетов на сетевом принтере, но там под windows server 2000. Была идея то же самое поискать в настройках. Но если бы такое было в настройках самого принтера, то все печатали бы с задержками. Поэтому мысль отпала. В любом случае, смогу попробовать что-то сделать только завтра. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: > хотел попробовать подключить другой компьютер к данному порту свитчаэто было бы верным решением, с целью проверить исправность сетевой карты

Answer (score 0):

Свич и сетевая вариант прелюбопытнейший, но я бы предложил посмотреть на то, как идет подготовка файла к печати. Дело в том, что под купсом есть старая проблема - графические файлы. Поковыряй дрова, параметры печати и тд. )))

Comment: > С других машин сканы печатаются тоже нормально.Установлена была Ubuntu 9.04, поставил 10.04 - не помогло.Внимательно прочтите с самого начала